# File structure php templates within folders

Tags: php, file, structure, public

It is a question about how to structure template files... So my job, is to do the templates, then, someone else integrates the real data and they are in charge on putting them live.

It is a big project..... and I have been told to tidy up the files, as I have all of them in the same folder...

I have:

- folder: **css**

  ```
  - bootstrap.min.css
  - featherlight.css
  - owl.carousel.css
  - font-awesome.min.css
  - style.css (all styles for all templates)
  ```
- folder: **js**

  ```
  - jquery
  - bootstrap.min.js
  - featherlight.js
  - owl.carousel.js
  - respond.min.js
  - modernizr.js
  - scripts.js (all javascript for interaction on templates)
  ```
- folder: **images**
- folder: **fonts**

  ```
  - folder with client fonts (Agenda Medium and Agenda Light)
  - font awesome font files
  - icomooon font files
  ```
- and then all the files:

  ```
  - index.php
  - header.php
  - navigation.php
  - navigation_home.php
  - footer.php
  - footer_myAccount.php
  - sidebar_products.php
  - sidebar.php
  - preferences_myAccount.php
  - dashboard_myAccount.php
  - orders_myAccount.php
  - filters_product.php
  - filters_event.php
  - filters_account.php
  - our_blog.php
  - single_article.php
  - events.php
  - single_event.php
  - producers.php
  - single_producer.php
  - countries.php
  - single_country.php
  - regions.php
  - single_regions.php
  - results.php
  ```

And I just don't know how can I tidy this. I have been looking around and a lot of people mentioned they put all templates in the "public" folder. I don't have a public folder at the moment, but even if I create it, I can't put all the files in there, as I have been told to tidy them....

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

For first, sorry for my english.

Many people use many cases for structure of applications. I try explain basically rules.

1) Statis files (js, css, fonts, sprites) should be separatelly with application. As good solution it can be place on subdomain (e.g. st.domain.tld). And all links for this resources must be absolute. (but physically it can be just nested directory for application).

2) Uploaded users media should be like static files -- separated domain, e.g. fs.domain.tld. Full download links (or segmented data like host, dir, filename, size) can be store on database.

3) Your backend application must be separate for general parts: core (framework), app (modules, controllers), templates (if need). Core (framework) can be used for many copies of application or different applications which use one framework copy. Physically, application directory can be locate in any path, and in public server directory can be locate only index.php and .htaccess (if need).

Not strict example (e.g. only) for structure of application directories:

> ~/framework/ -- can be place in ~/htdocs/domain.tld/
>
> ~/htdocs/domain.tld/public_html/index.php
>
> ~/htdocs/domain.tld/static_files/*(js,css.etc) -- can be bind to
>   subdomain or allowed with symlink from public_html
>
> ~/htdocs/domain.tld/application/
>
> ~/htdocs/domain.tld/application/modules/*(controllers/actions)
>
> ~/htdocs/domain.tld/application/views/ -- can be separate same as controllers (dir structure copy) and named as controllers and/or actions -- it allows bind same path prefixes/namespaces for auto include views of controllers.

Honestly, this is complex question and my answer for example explain less information about structure of application.

Maybe somebody can/want edit or add more info for my answer -- welcome.